# Windows START command loading wrong version of Visual Studio

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I just upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019 (queue the applause).  All is well and good, and I have both environments running, but...

I have a batch file that I use to start VS 2017 using the windows START and a bunch of other programs (fiddler, postman, etc).  When I changed the path in the batch file to use visual studio 2019 it still loads up visual studio 2017

Neither of the Visual Studio environments are in my path and when I run the command from my command prompt

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

it loads up visual studio 2019 (yay), but when I use the START command it loads visual studio 2017.

I am on a windows 10 machine with Command Extensions turned on

```
START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\" devenv.exe
```

Anyone have any idea why the **START** Command is loading vs2017?

Thanks

Comment: Put an empty quoted argument like `start "" /D ...` since `start` might interpret the first quoted string as a window title unexpectedly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start /D "somepath" somexecutable
```

does not starts the executable located in somepath, it merely sets the current working directory to somepath.

What you want is this:

```
START /D "somepath" "somepath/somexecutable"
```

which in your case expands to

```
START /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

But even though you think `devenv` is not in your path, it must be somehow. To find where it is found  try

```
where devenv
```

Comment: You can quickly test this for yourself by copying c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe to a C:\mydir\calc.exe .  If you run `start /d "C:\mydir" calc.exe` it runs the calculator from the path rather than the one in C:\mydir.

Comment: Thanks StephaneM.  You solved most of the mystery, and you helped me find the missing piece because devenv is not in my path.  What I discovered and think happened is that I have Visual Studio set to load up the last SLN file.  And in Explorer I have SLN files set to open with VS2017 (e.g.  type: c:\>foo.sln and it will open in vs2017).  By using your suggestion windows asked me if I still want to use VS2017 to open or VS2019.  Picking VS2019 and it all works.!